# Why Can I not do a subrequest for a Partial View for each request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In `_Layout.cshtml`, I have this part of code

```
<div>
      @Html.Action("BestStudent", "Student")
</div>
```

In Student Controller I have created BestStudent method as below

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    private UniversityInitial dbAllStudents  = new UniversityInitial();

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult BestStudent()
    {
        var best = dbAllStudents.Students
            .Where(s => s.LastName.StartsWith("M")&s.FirstName.StartsWith("E") & s.City.StartsWith("T"));
        return PartialView("_BestStudent", best);
    }
}
```

In Views/Shared folder I have created the Partial View named `_BestStudent.cshtml` strongly typed for Student model as below:

```
@model UniversityApp.Models.Student

<h3 class="text-danger">Student of the year</h3>
Name : @Model.FirstName
Last Name : @Model.LastName
City: @Model.City
```

Build succeed but when I run it I got one exception like:

> "Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil...

and the breakpoint is to the line of code below:

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("BestStudent", "Student")
</div>
```

So I guess something wrong happens here, but I can not figure it out what

Comment: what are u doing exactly? tell me your scenario

Comment: Because your query returns a collection of `Student`, not a single `Student` which is required by your view (hence an exception is thrown). Change the query to add `.FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: also put the complete error not just part of it

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your suggest worked perfectly and was exactly what I needed.

Comment: read this carefully : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @StephenMuecke please include the answer so he can accept it.

Comment: @Valkyriee, You should just edit your answer (I was not even sure if OP wanted a single `Student` or collection - in which case the view would have need to be `@model IEnumerable<Student>` with a `foreach` loop)

Comment: @StephenMuecke i didn't ask mate =) i did answer. yeah me too actually i had no idea if its a list/object he wanted to return, he needs to edit his question.

Comment: Oops, that comment was supposed to say 'answer', not 'question' :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Alright Done =)

Comment: You should consider accepting the answer by @Valkyriee

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Fix this Query like below:

```
var best = dbAllStudents.Students
                        .Where(s => s.LastName.StartsWith("M")&s.FirstName.StartsWith("E") & s.City.StartsWith("T")).FirstOrDefault();
return PartialView("_BestStudent", best);
```

Credit Goes to @StephenMuecke